# Read-only filesystem after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, apt, bug-reporting

So before I reinstalled Ubuntu, I had the same problem. However I think las time it may have been a corrupted filesystem since there were more errors. However when I tried to do `sudo apt-get update` it ended with error

```
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

it also showed the same (30: Read only file system) error but it said it was unable to fetch some packages. I don't fully understand whats going on, since I just reinstalled Ubuntu and had formatted the hard drive.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Edit:
I had to reboot my system because Firefox crashed and now I'm stuck at initframs again. Tried `fsck /dev/sda1`  but it didn't work. It said that file doesn't exist. Exit doesnt work and now I'm reinstalling ubuntu for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your drive is failing. Try booting from a LiveCD/USB and run something like smartmontools to see if the drive's S.M.A.R.T. lists that it's had some failures. Very important to do on SSDs, though HDDs aren't immune to this sort of issue either.

You could also do the same through GParted in the LiveCD itself. E.g. [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)